# Removing WPF ListView/GridView highlight chrome

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls, highlight

I have WPF ListView with GridView view and I want to remove any trace of row highlight.

This useful piece of code can be found in one answer on this site:

```
     <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
           <Setter Property="Control.Focusable" Value="False"/>
           <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
              </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

However, while this change helps to remove most of the highlight, it does not remove the horizontal bar that still appears when mouse moves over the ListView row. How do I remove it?

I have dealt with the similar problem involving Button and found a solution that changes Button template by removing its chrome.

In this case of ListView/GridView I am unable to find the corresponding chrome and template to change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have the Windows SDK installed, you can find the XAML source for all default styles (assuming you installed the samples) in:

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Samples\WPFSamples.zip

The zip file contains a folder Core which contains AeroTheme, LunaTheme etc which contain the source for default styles. Unfortunately these files are pretty large (~8500 lines for Aero) and not very well structured or formatted (IMO).

The default control template for a ListViewItem looks like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
  <Border CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <Border Name="InnerBorder" CornerRadius="1" BorderThickness="1">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11" />
          <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Name="UpperHighlight" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="#75FFFFFF" />
        <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
      </Grid>
    </Border>
  </Border>

  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemHoverFill}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCCF0FF" />
      <Setter TargetName="UpperHighlight" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedFill}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB" />
      <Setter TargetName="InnerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#80FFFFFF" />
      <Setter TargetName="UpperHighlight" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
      <Setter TargetName="UpperHighlight" Property="Fill" Value="#40FFFFFF" />
    </Trigger>

    <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedInactiveFill}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCFCFCF" />
    </MultiTrigger>

    <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedHoverFill}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB" />
    </MultiTrigger>

    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Your best bet for removing all highlighting is probably to replace the ControlTemplate with you own that just includes the GridViewRowPresenter (maybe in a single Border). Don't forget to include the Trigger that greys the items when the control is disabled.

Comment: Upper highlight must be it! I was looking at template here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788717.aspx
and since it must be for a different theme, I couldn't explain the bar.

Comment: I can confirm that UpperHighlight rectangle was the culprit. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing... only in WPF have I had to completely override a style to get rid of a single highlight element.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not in front of a Windows PC to test this right now but I had a similar issue with listboxes which I fixed by putting the following into my Window.Resources

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
```

Not sure if it will work with your listview though.

Comment: Several blogs and anwers point to this method but, for some reason, it never worked for me.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked for me when I put it in my window resources with Style targetType="ListViewItem".  I also added a line to set the SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey to SystemColors.WindowTextColor otherwise to prevent my text color from switching to the background color (and thus disappearing).

Comment: For me it works on ListView withOUT Gridview.  But NOT with Gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I'm not seeing any line at all. What's your default theme right now? Luna, Aero, etc.? It could be that yours is different than mine, therefore a difference in chrome. Are there any other particular settings on your `ListView`?

[Style Snooper](http://arbel.net/blog/archive/2006/11/05/Revamped-Style-Snooper.aspx) or [Show Me The Template](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/) might help you track down the visual element responsible for the line you're seeing. You may also be interested in [re-templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747.aspx) your `ListView` to get the effect you want.

Comment: It is Vista theme, I believe it is Aero since I have glass effects. Indeed people on XP don't see the highlight bar.