# Creating custom ListView from scratch in Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, expression-blend

I already looked through the internet but could not find a tutorial that showed the **creation of a ListView in Expression Blend**. I do not want to modify existing ListViews that are part of Blend, as I have done that already.

I need a tutorial that shows the **first steps of creating a custom ListView** and, in my case, specifically states all the **parts the ListView consists of**.

A button for example, can be created in Blend by drawing a Rectangle, adding a ContentPresenter and converting that into a Button user control. I would like to do the same thing for a ListView.

I went through that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362220/writing-drawing-my-own-listbox-listview-control-from-scratch/) already but since it is about WinForms I could not draw any helpful conclusions.

I am thankful for links to **similar posts**, **tutorials** and even **code snippets**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long night of further research I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252047/removing-wpf-listview-gridview-highlight-chrome). I installed the Windows SDK and there are files that contain the ControlTemplates for WPF Controls. Using them as a blueprint gives me the possibility of creating my own desired version of the ListView.

Comment: [That MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/ms788717(v=vs.90).aspx) thoroughly describes the control templates for several WPF controls.